# Make all gradients to white to be gradient to transparent

Tags: transparency, gdi+, system.drawing, colormatrix

I'm trying to get a efficient code that opens a existing image and makes it transparent. The thing is that I would like all possible colours that is some what gradient to white to be gradient to transparent. I have played around a bit with the Color Matrix but fails... So instead I'm doing alot of stuff that might be totaly unnecessary. My solutions is as following.

1) open existing file.

2) make a new image as grayscale from the source

3) invert the graysscale

4) apply the red value as alpha from the inverted grayscale image, pixel per pixel to new image. other RGB values is extraxted from the orginal file. (sorry for my sloppy functions... just had to do a quick test and see if it was possible)

This works somehow good except it takes alot of time when processing larger images (about 3500x2000 pixels) Is it somehow possible to do this direct with the ColorMatrix in order to skip my pixel per pixel process? Or are there other methods? I have been thinking of masking etc but do not have any experience at all of that.

Current code do also make other colours than black slightly transparent (less intense) since the usage of gray scale as input.

```
'VB.NET
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim args() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
    Dim Path As String = String.Empty

    If args.Count = 2 Then
        Path = args(1)
    End If

    Try
        Dim image1 As Bitmap = CType(Image.FromFile(Path, True), Bitmap)
        Dim image2 As New Bitmap(image1.Width, image1.Height)

        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image2)

        Dim myColorMatrix As New ColorMatrix
        Dim invColor As New ColorMatrix

        Dim imageAttr As New ImageAttributes

        myColorMatrix.Matrix00 = 0.3F
        myColorMatrix.Matrix01 = 0.3F
        myColorMatrix.Matrix02 = 0.3F

        myColorMatrix.Matrix10 = 0.59F
        myColorMatrix.Matrix11 = 0.59F
        myColorMatrix.Matrix12 = 0.59F

        myColorMatrix.Matrix20 = 0.11F
        myColorMatrix.Matrix21 = 0.11F
        myColorMatrix.Matrix22 = 0.11F

        myColorMatrix.Matrix33 = 1.0
        myColorMatrix.Matrix44 = 1.0

        imageAttr.SetColorMatrix(myColorMatrix, ColorAdjustType.Default, ColorAdjustType.Default)
        g.DrawImage(image1, New Rectangle(0, 0, image1.Width, image1.Height), 0, 0, image1.Width, image1.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttr)

        invColor.Matrix00 = -1
        invColor.Matrix11 = -1
        invColor.Matrix22 = -1
        invColor.Matrix33 = 1
        invColor.Matrix44 = 1
        invColor.Matrix40 = 1
        invColor.Matrix41 = 1
        invColor.Matrix42 = 1

        imageAttr.SetColorMatrix(invColor, ColorAdjustType.Default, ColorAdjustType.Default)
        g.DrawImage(image2, New Rectangle(0, 0, image1.Width, image1.Height), 0, 0, image1.Width, image1.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttr)

        Dim myColor As New Color
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        Dim myAlpha As Integer = 0
        Dim orgColor(2) As Integer

        Do Until y = image1.Height
            Do Until x = image1.Width
                'Get alpha
                myAlpha = toRGB(image2.GetPixel(x, y))

                orgColor = currentRGB(image1.GetPixel(x, y))

                myColor = Color.FromArgb(myAlpha, orgColor(0), orgColor(1), orgColor(2))

                image2.SetPixel(x, y, myColor)
                x = x + 1
            Loop
            x = 0
            y = y + 1
        Loop

        image2.Save("C:\test\transparent.png", ImageFormat.Png)

        image1.Dispose()
        image2.Dispose()
        g.Dispose()

    Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString & vbNewLine & " There was an error opening the bitmap." _
            & "Please check the path.")
    End Try

End Sub
Private Function toRGB(ByVal Color As Color) As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    r = Color.R
    Return r
End Function
Private Function currentRGB(ByRef color As Color) As Array
    Dim currRGB(2) As Integer
    currRGB(0) = color.R
    currRGB(1) = color.G
    currRGB(2) = color.B
    Return currRGB
End Function
End Module
```

Comment: How about giving us a before and an after image? And telling us how long it takes?

Comment: SetPixel is horrendously slow. A solution using LockBits and pointers will run a hundred times faster (and you can get rid of ColorMatrix completely).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `system()` to get ImageMagick to do this for you. It is free and available [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

It also has Windows .NET bindings available - see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) so you could call ImageMagick's library functions directly from your program without needing `system()`.

I think what you are trying to do can be done like this at the command line:

```
convert input.bmp \( +clone -colorspace gray \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite output.png
```

I benchmarked the above on an image 3500x2000 and it takes 0.8 seconds - no idea if that is any good compared to your code or not!

Answer (score 1):

This is completely untested code (I don't even know if it compiles correctly), but it should give you an idea of how to do it as fast as you can go (without using the GPU, of course):

```
public static void AlphaGray(
    Bitmap bmp,
    int threshold )
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle( Point.Empty, bmp.Size );
    BitmapData bd = bmp.LockBits( r, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb );
    unsafe
    {
        byte* p = (byte*)bd.Scan0.ToPointer();
        for ( int i = r.Height * r.Width; i > 0; i--, p +=4 )
        {
            var avg = (p[0] + p[1] + p[2]) /3;
            var bx = p[0] - avg; 
            var gx = p[1] - avg; 
            var rx = p[2] - avg; 
            if( bx*bx + gx*gx + rx*rx < threshold )
                p[3] = (byte)avg;
        }
    }
    bmp.UnlockBits( bd );
}
```